# Choose from map with android marshmallow

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-bundle

Now I'm using android map clicklistener to allow user to choose location from map. When the click the map the chosen location latitude and longitude are printed correctly in the toast, then I send this data to another fragment through bundle.
On android marshmallow devices it always transferred with null value, even it's working properly with all other versions.
I don't know what is the problem, so I'll be blessed for any help

Here is my code

```
try {
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        CameraUpdate Update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10);
        map.animateCamera(Update);

        final Marker TP = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(""));
        TP.setDraggable(true);

        map.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), point.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String latMap = String.valueOf(point.latitude);
                String lngMap = String.valueOf(point.longitude);

                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).aqarLat = String.valueOf(point.latitude);;
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).aqarLong = String.valueOf(point.longitude);

                myBundle = new Bundle();

                myBundle.putString("latMap" , latMap);
                myBundle.putString("lngMap" , lngMap);

                sharedPreferences.edit().putString("latMap", String.valueOf(point.latitude)).commit();
                sharedPreferences.edit().putString("longMap", String.valueOf(point.longitude)).commit();

                TP.setPosition(point);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see any code sending the `myBundle` to fragment. Can you post that part of the code as well?